# Xcode 8.3 - How to change autocompletion delay?

Tags: xcode, xcode8

When typing code in Xcode it sometimes does not autocomplete, or only autocomplete if I wait a second.
If I manually press the autocompletion hotkey, it appears instantly - so it's ready / indexed already, but just not showing.

Is there a way to reduce the delay until Xcode shows the autocompletion?